# What account should be used to create a new web application(-Application Pool -Configurable) - help

Tags: web-application, application-pool

I'm creating a new web application on a new SP install.
I logged in ok to the central admin site with a setup account.But when i'm on the CREATE NEW WEB APPLICATION page and i get to Application Pool the default account(Configurable) it wnats me to choose is the Farm Acount.
Should i be using the Farm accout or i have to register a new managed account to use.
I have Application Pool accts already setup.Is that what i should be using or the farm acct?
THanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The application pool account will be used by the code when the code is executed in "Run with elevated previlage" option. Its better to use a different managed account other than Farm administrator as through elevated previlage code, the user can get the highest access level to SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks Manju.before i created a managed account the only acct that was listed to set a new web app was a farms account.But since i created a managed account i use it and i understand that should be the right account to use.